# Dependency convergence error while validating Hazelcast project

Tags: maven, hazelcast

Getting this error for "mvn clean validate". Is this issue the same as https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage/issues/133? Can someone please help to resolve this?
I haven't changed pom.xml.

```
Dependency convergence error for com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4 paths to dependency are:
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-grpc:5.0-20210531.092806-178
        +-io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.34.0
          +-io.grpc:grpc-core:1.34.0
            +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-grpc:5.0-20210531.092806-178
        +-io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.34.0
          +-io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.34.0
            +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-grpc:5.0-20210531.092806-178
        +-io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.34.0
          +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-grpc:5.0-20210531.092806-178
        +-com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre
          +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.5.1
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-grpc:5.0-20210531.092806-178
        +-io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.34.0
          +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-grpc:5.0-20210531.092806-178
        +-io.grpc:grpc-api:1.34.0
          +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-files-gcs:5.0-20210531.093025-176
        +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.1.5
          +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:2.1.5
            +-io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.34.0
              +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-files-gcs:5.0-20210531.093025-176
        +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.1.5
          +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:2.1.5
            +-io.grpc:grpc-alts:1.34.0
              +-io.grpc:grpc-grpclb:1.34.0
                +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-files-gcs:5.0-20210531.093025-176
        +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.1.5
          +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:2.1.5
            +-io.grpc:grpc-alts:1.34.0
              +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    and
    +-com.hazelcast:hazelcast-distribution:5.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.hazelcast.jet:hazelcast-jet-files-gcs:5.0-20210531.093025-176
        +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.1.5
          +-com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:2.1.5
            +-com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.13.0
              +-com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
    
    [WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
    Failed while enforcing releasability. See above detailed error message.
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-tools) on project hazelcast-distribution: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Is Dependency Convergence an enterprise requirement? What are you using it for?

Comment: no requirement, also I haven't changed pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to disable the dependencyConvergence check in the POM, or you need to add an entry to the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your POM which contains the version of `error_prone_annotations` that you want to use.

Comment: I added all dependencies in dependencyManagement and it worked, did you mean adding only error_prone_annotations?

Comment: You can add all of them. For dependency convergence to work, you need the ones that create convergence errors.